# Motivation behind the representation of differential cross sections using histograms

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

From my lecture notes:

> In most cases a cross section is represented in a differential way with respect to one or more
>   observables. While it is possible to make a theoretical prediction for a distribution dσ/dO with
>   respect to a continuous observable O it is not possible in general to measure the differential cross
>   section at an exact value of that observable. This is because the probability of the observable being
>   exactly that value is 0, it is only non-vanishing if we consider the probability for the observable to
>   be in an interval containing the value. For this reason differential cross sections are represented as histograms.

I know that the differential cross section $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$ represents the proportion of particles scattered in an infinitesimally small angle $d\Omega$, but I really don't understand the significance of the statement: *the probability of the observable being exactly that value is 0, it is only non-vanishing if we consider the probability for the observable to be in an interval containing the value.*

What is reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 0):

> it is not possible in general to measure the differential cross
>   section at an exact value of that observable.

This sounds clear, $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$ at exactly $\Omega_0$ would imply the need of an infinitely small detector.

> This is because the
>   probability of the observable being exactly that value is 0, it is
>   only non-vanishing ...

yes, $\sigma$ measured with such a detector would be vanishing...

> if we consider the probability for the observable
>   to be in an interval containing the value.

"the observable" stands here for $\Omega$. I read the message as - we have a detector of the finite size $\Delta \Omega$ and $\Omega_0$ is inside.

> For this reason
>   differential cross sections are represented as histograms.

The final meaning of the sentence is for me a bit like - once we measure  $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$ at some point, it is rather somewhat averaged quantity  $\frac{\Delta\sigma}{\Delta\Omega}$ at that point.